# query_vars treat as single var from URL

Tags: functions, wp-query

I want to use the link parameter from URL as one query_var.
If I visit the page where [flipwoo] is in, for example:
`https://test.com/test/?link=https://test.com/?download_file=1953&order=wc_order_zHOH4RI97k9mR&email=test%40gmail.com&key=91c44b50-6922-4976-ac57-6d499136eead`
the following is echoed:
`https://test.com/?download_file=1953`
but I want the whole URL after ?link= to be echoed:
`https://test.com/?download_file=1953&order=wc_order_zHOH4RI97k9mR&email=test%40gmail.com&key=91c44b50-6922-4976-ac57-6d499136eead`

Where is the mistake?

```
function themeslug_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'link';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'themeslug_query_vars' );

function get_woolink() {
    $linked = get_query_var( 'link', 1 );
    echo $linked;
}

add_shortcode('flipwoo', 'get_woolink');
```

Comment: get_query_var() only retrieves public query variables that are recognized by WP_Query. This means that if you create your own custom URLs with their own query variables, get_query_var() will not retrieve them without some further work (see below). - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Comment: As you can see in my code, I've done this function themeslug_query_vars

Comment: ? is a special operator in the querystring, you will probably need to register each querystring parameter, such as email, key, etc and try to pass them back to the filter.

Comment: I agree, it looks like the problem is you didn't encode the value for your link parameter correctly so PHP isn't parsing it the way you expect. If the whole thing is the one value, it should be `?link=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2F%3Fdownload_file%3D1953%26order%3Dwc_order_zHOH4RI97k9mR%26email%3Dtest%2540gmail.com%26key%3D91c44b50-6922-4976-ac57-6d499136eead`. To encode the value correctly use urlencode in PHP or encodeURIComponent in JavaScript.

Comment: urlencode() worked. Thanks!